Access VBA Export Report as PDF/A
I need to export an Access report to PDF/A with VBA. I saw this solution (How do I save an MS Access Report as PDF/A) which I didn't try yet, but since it's over 5 years old, I would like to know if there is a builtin solution in Access' VBA.

There is not. The referenced link is still relevant.
